# KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, reindex

I have a data frame with the following columns:

```
job_post.columns 

Index(['Job.ID_list', 'Provider', 'Status', 'Slug', 'Title', 'Position',
   'Company', 'City', 'State.Name', 'State.Code', 'Address', 'Latitude',
   'Longitude', 'Industry', 'Job.Description', 'Requirements', 'Salary',
   'Listing.Start', 'Listing.End', 'Employment.Type', 'Education.Required',
   'Created.At', 'Updated.At', 'Job.ID_desc', 'text'],
  dtype='object')
```

I want to select only the following columns from the dataframe:

```
columns_job_post = ['Job.ID_listing', 'Slug', 'Position', 'Company', 'Industry', 'Job.Description','Employment.Type', 'Education.Required', 'text'] # columns to keep
```

However, I get the result:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported
```

I solved the issue by writing:

```
jobs_final = job_post.reindex(columns = columns_job_post)
```

Similarly, I have a data frame with the following columns:

````
cand_exp.columns

Index(['Applicant.ID', 'Position.Name', 'Employer.Name', 'City', 'State.Name',
   'State.Code', 'Start.Date', 'End.Date', 'Job.Description', 'Salary',
   'Can.Contact.Employer', 'Created.At', 'Updated.At'],
  dtype='object')```
````

I also selected just **some** columns from the whole list using `.loc` but I didn't get the `KeyError: Passing list-like...`

````
columns_cand_exp = ['Applicant.ID', 'Position.Name', 'Employer.Name', 'Job.Description', 'Salary']``` # columns to keep

resumes_final = cand_exp.loc[:, columns_cand_exp]
````

**What is the reason for this?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first example you introduced column names that are **not** exists in the original data frame (ex: `Job.ID_listing`).

In the second example all the columns **were already** in the original data frame.

as the error says: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with **any missing labels** .....

Comment: I see it now. I was not aware of that. Thank you very much!